# How to include a gigantic 14GB+ folder in the NSIS installer of an Electron app?

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I have an app made using Electron. I am creating the NSIS installer for the app using Electron Builder. The Electron app has a dependency to something similar to a videogame (lets call it a videogame but it's not a videogame) that is 14GB+ folder and contains large binaries (.dlls, .exes, etc.).

I need to create the NSIS installer for my app so the user installing the app gets both the app and the videogame dependency completely offline, without internet.

I am aware the NSIS installer cannot be larger than 2GB.

A solution I am thinking of:

1. Create a install.zip that contains NSIS installer and videogame.zip.
2. In the .nsh script, extract the videogame.zip via relative path to wherever I need the contents

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I cannot download it from a particular endpoint online because this has to be an offline installation. If there is no way to override that limit, then I suppose the only other alternative is to provide the installer with the 14GB+ data?

Comment: Any reason you can't just ship 2 files (the app installer and the videogames archive)?

Comment: @0xFF I think shipping both of them together is the best way to go, yes.

Comment: Hmm, since we need to think outside the box here - does your app need to be installed or would it be ok to just put a zip somewhere and create a shortcut to the .exe?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve this problem. I just used an alternative: I used a .zip file instead of NSIS.

I included both the dependency and the Electron app together.